# Is $\{ \sin(\sqrt {nx} \mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ is equicontinuous in $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Is $\{\sin(\sqrt {nx}\mid n\in \mathbb N\}$ is equicontinuous in $C[0,1]$?

As near $0$, its derivative is unbounded, so function is not even uniformly continuous . So not equicontinuous .

Please tell me I am wrong or not

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For a fixed $n$, it is not true that the derivative of the function $f(x) = \sin(\sqrt{n}x)$ is unbounded, nor is it true that $f$ fails to be uniformly continuous.  Note that "uniformly continuous" describes a function, but does not describe a family of functions

Comment: Dear Sir then how to argue to show equicontinous family.

Comment: I'd start with the definition of equicontinuity. When you try to apply that definition to this family, where do you get stuck?

Comment: Dear sir how to estimate |sin \sqrt nx -\sin \sqrt ny|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that for any $\delta>0$, there exists an $n \in \Bbb N$ for which $f(x) = \sin(\sqrt{nx})$ satisfies 
$$
|f(\delta) - f(0)| \geq \frac 12.
$$

---

Regarding your comment on the question itself: we could use the [sum-to-product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) to note that
$$
\sin(\sqrt{nx}) - \sin(\sqrt{ny}) = 2\sin(\frac 12 (\sqrt{nx} - \sqrt{ny}))\cos(\frac 12 (\sqrt{nx} + \sqrt{ny})).
$$
Alternatively, we can simply use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Comment: Dear Sir extremely sorry but there is typo in my question as I was typing with mobile phone. I could not see difference . nx both in square root please help me

Comment: @MathLover The answer and approach are still the same in this case